# Solr Facet Range with Integers

Tags: python, django, solr

My index contains peoples information, name, age, phone email etc.

I am faceting on Age. I group ages kinda like Date Range functionality.

My ranges are:

```
    0 to 10
    11 to 20
    21 to 30
    31 to 40 etc etc
```

When I do a query:

```
    ?q=*:*&facet=true&fq=age:[21+TO+30]
```

It returns all the ages I want in the range 21 to 30, but it also returns the age 3.

```
    ?q=*:*&facet=true&fq=age:[11+TO+20]
```

this does the same thing, but it returns the age 2.

```
    ?q=*:*&facet=true&fq=age:[0+TO+10]
```

this does the same thing, but it returns the age 1.
Can anyone explain this to me - is it a in solr?

Comment: please post the line of your schema.xml of the age field.

Comment: Also can you post the full Solr Request.. and the results from Solr

Comment: Schema Definition:
<field name="age" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

That is the full request.

Comment: Have you changed the schema recently without re-building the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From trawling the web I found that Solr indexes all data as strings - even when you define it as an integer. Its still a string in Solr:

`<field name="age" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

So what I needed to do was:

`<field name="age" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

If you want to order your integers this is the way, I assume the "sint" type was designed specifically for this.

Cheers

Comment: As Lucene is the underlying engine, all indexed values are sort ordered lexicographically. The "sint" data type in solr represents a sortable int, which sorts integer values as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In your request, you don't have any [facet queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_:_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting). You are using [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview). Which will narrow you're results set down.

Perhaps you could try adding some facet.query's to your request and copy the results from the facet.counts area, in to your question above. At the very least this will tell you how many results solr thinks are in the different age ranges:

```
&facet.query=age:[21+TO+30]&facet.query=age:[11+TO+20]&facet.query=age:[0+TO+10]&facet.query=age:[*+TO+2]&facet.query=age:[*+TO+3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing of solr but I would guess that it is treating your ranges as alphabetical rather than numeric.

You may want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results) which has links to various documents discussing a very similar issue