# SOLR: Equal number of results in Range faceting

Tags: solr

Is it possible to have equal number of results in SOLR range faceting.

For example: I want to do facet over a list of prices and distribute it equally in 3 parts - 100,100,120,130,300,360,480,500,600,650,700,800

So the results should be :
100-130(4)
300-500(4)
600-800(4)

Comment: Yes, please see this previous answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11329853/130988) I posted for question [33956](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33956/130988).

In brief, the method I use is:

1. Pre-process documents to store a price that has been rounded up to the nearest "nice round number" facet boundary
2. Request all facets on the rounded prices
3. Combine these rounded-price facets into a few large facet "segments" to get roughly equal number of documents in each segment.
4. When user selects to filter, do a filter query for the price range of that segment.