# Dynamic range faceting in solr

Tags: solr

I Have a field which contains absolute numeric values,I want solr to return facets for that fields as ranges(say 1-10 ,11-20).

These ranges has to be dynamic since I cannot provide the start and end values ,which are mandatory for facet range queries.Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Or this there a way write a subquery which returns the maximum value for that field and use the value in the main query(There can be only one query)

This question was asked previously but there are no proper answers.

Comment: Had you removed the previous question?

Comment: I had not asked ,but i found one similar question

Comment: Had you taken a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956/how-to-get-facet-ranges-in-solr-results

Comment: In that they can specify ranges beforehand,In my case I cannot do that

Comment: You're going to have to query for the appropriate range first, then apply your application logic to what those ranges should be - there is no built-in support for this in Solr. So doing it with just one query is probably out (you could however have a small gap with start/end, then merge those buckets in your frontend).